# Windows Phone | Dialog Window Cross Icon and Hardware Back Button

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows Phone Application. I have a pop up displayed when an icon is tapped on the screen. That pop has a cross icon on the top right corner so that user can tap on the cross icon and pop up gets closed? 
Pop also gets closed when user presses the hardware back button.
I want to ask if it is OK to place a cross icon on pop up windows because there is two way to close the same pop(from hardware back button and from cross icon)???? 
Is it OK from Windows Phone Certification certification point of View.

Answer (score 1):

From certification point of view its not a problem as long as the back button also does the same.

Just remember that many users have had WP for a while and you as a developer are expect to support native mechanisms while doing every thing you want to do on top of it.